# Difference between delete and force delete in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, command

i am really confused what is the difference between DELETE and FORCE DELETE.
how `rm -r dir` is different from the `rm -f file`.
Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the man pages of rm you will see what it does exactly:

```
-f           Attempt to remove the files without prompting for confirma-
             tion, regardless of the file's permissions.  If the file does
             not exist, do not display a diagnostic message or modify the
             exit status to reflect an error.  The -f option overrides any
             previous -i options.

-R           Attempt to remove the file hierarchy rooted in each file
             argument.  The -R option implies the -d option.  If the -i
             option is specified, the user is prompted for confirmation
             before each directory's contents are processed (as well as
             before the attempt is made to remove the directory).  If the
             user does not respond affirmatively, the file hierarchy
             rooted in that directory is skipped.

-r           Equivalent to -R.
```